# Terminating Java User Input While Loop

Tags: java

I am learning Java day 1 and I have a very simple code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     while(input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

After I input any sentence, the while loop seems to not terminate.
How would I need to change this so that the I could break out of the loop when the sentence is all read?

Comment: This code does not read "sentences". Java doesn't know about sentences. It reads tokens. You need to define what a sentence means. Any word ending in a punctuation mark? Or, what you have now, but with end of file terminating input. On windows ctrl-z. Everywhere else ctrl-d.

Comment: What I meant was my code is trying to get a user input and break them into words printing them separately. So as in "sentences" I guess I meant user inputs. My code prints each word of the user input separated by spaces but does not terminate the while loop when done displaying the last "word".

Comment: @2AMCoffee
It is working as you expected! I am wondering about the way you run your program!
[onecompiler sample](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y64whjue)

Comment: Is reading with nextLine() and splitting it a better method?

Comment: I just run it with java Main.java in terminal and I'm not sure why for me the code doesn't terminate :(.

Comment: `nextLine()` reads the whole line at once [scanner_nextline](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm#:~:text=nextLine()%20method%20advances%20this,beginning%20of%20the%20next%20line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasNext()` method always checks if the `Scanner` has another token in its input. A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern that matches whitespace by default.

- Whitespace includes not only the space character, but also tab space `(\t)`, line feed `(\n)`, and [more other characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))

`hasNext()` checks the input and returns true if it has another non-whitespace character.

---

Your approach is correct if you want to take input from the console continuously. However, if you just want to have single user input(i.e a sentence or list of words) it is better to read the whole input and then split it accordingly.
eg:-

```
String str = input.nextLine();
for(String s : str.split(" ")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple workaround for this would be to stop whenever you find a **stop** or any set of strings you would like!

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        if (word.equals("stop")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("THE END!");
```